# "What is important are not" vs " What are important are not"

Tags: grammatical-number, interrogatives, existentials

Example:

> What **is/are** important are not your mistakes, but how you respond to them.

Which option makes more sense grammatically?

Comment: Native speakers would tend to use "is".  What is important is not your clothes and your possessions but your character.

Comment: @TRomano I think gramatically you need and "is" in the first "is/are" pair. I'm struggling to figure out the actual reason other then the "What is important" is a figure of speech meaning essentially "Don't worry about thing A which seems bad instead worry about thing B which is the more important consequence." 

The other "is/are" pair (not asked about the OP but which you changed to "is") can be both though no?

Comment: @DRF: What are important are... is avoided, to be sure.

Comment: I conceptualize *mistakes* as a subject complement (a completer of the subject after a linking verb) rather than an object (a recipient of action). There are other systems which use these labels and define sentence parts differently. The OP does not start with *what is important* as a subject, but asks which word should follow *what.* Whether the complement is singular or plural will certainly influence the main verb in the sentence then: *Who is nice is that user, AmD. Who aren't nice are those users who disagree with Jim Reynolds.*  No??

Comment: @Jim Reynolds In this case that grammar is a little more difficult than I thought. I see. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of them make sense, grammatically, because *mistakes* is plural and *how you respond* is singular.

If we are forced to make a choice between the two, the best option would be to use *is,* because it's less of a stretch to consider *mistakes* as a collection (that is a singular set of mistakes), than it is to try to justify writing *What are important is (or are) how you respond . . . .*

I would personally not be comfortable writing *mistakes is* in this context, however, at least not in and I'm a pretty liberal grammarian (sometimes even a grammamatician). In conversational speech, it's the kind of thing many of us do without many others noticing or caring much.

The better option would be to re-write around the problem, for example:

*It is not your mistakes that are important, it is how you respond to them.*